# Error to create an sub-domain in OpenCart 1.5.6,

Tags: subdomain

Good morning,

I create all steps as usually for create an sub-domain:
1. I create an sub-domain using CPanel;
2. I specified from setting on ¨Address URL¨ as usually in OpenCart form : 
http://demo1.my-shopping.ro/

So, I don´t see the theme choose instead of those message which can be see if you will type in browser the address of my sub-domain.
What I don´t understand is if the steps is so simple, why don´t work?

I waiting much early is possible your answer and advice or other suggestion which can help me to resolve the error.

Thank you in advance for support and collaboration.
Best regards.

Comment: are you going to host opencart on sub-domain

Comment: Of course, How I described in my post, I create the sub-domain using CPanel, and I denominate the new store how OpenCart recommand. What I don´t know is why I cannot see my subdomain using my theme and what I want for my sub-domain. Can be a reason some priviledge from ftp? like allow 755 for the folder root (in my ex. demo1)?

Comment: copy your opencart to your subdomain folder `demo1` and edit confiq.php as per

Comment: Good morning, It is very difficult to understand something if it is not complete explained. So, thank you very much for support   mudasirahanger. But this topic will be read by many other OpenCart users which encountered the same problem as me. So, please explain better and clear the procedure in which I can add an sub-domain in OpenCart (create other stores using sub-domains) with steps necessary (including the name of folders and/or files which must be copy from base folder of site in sub-domain site folder). Thank you again for support and advice. I waiting your suggestion or advice.

Answer (score 0):

[image: creating sub domain]

first of all you need to create **sub domain** i.e`store2.yourdomain.com` as shown above or you can host it on **sub category** also i.e `www.yourdomain.com/store2/` then goto `yourdomain.com/admin` and in **opencart** admin panel goto **settings** click **Insert** button fill details as show below [image: opencart multi store settings] then move you clone to those folder e.g `store2` and edit config.php as show below

```
`<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://yourdomain.com/store2/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://yourdomain.com/store2/');


?>
```